# Compressing Guid based string to write on QR Code

Tags: javascript, cordova, compression, guid, qr-code

I am developing a phonegap application in html5/javascript. I have a string of around 1000 characters comprising of guids in below format

1=0a0a8907-40b9-4e81-8c4d-d01af26efb78;2=cd4713339;3=Cjdnd;4=19120581-21e5-42b9-b85f-3b8c5b1206d9;5=hdhsfsdfsd;6=30a21580-48f3-40e8-87a3-fa6e39e6412f; ...............

I have to write this particular string into a [QR code](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code). Is there any working technique to compress this string and store in QR code. The QR generated by this string is too complex and is not easily read by the QR scanner of mobile phones. Pls suggest the approach to reduce the size of string to around 200-250 character which can be easily read.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why is the GUID so long? A 64 bit GUID is good for 18 quintillion unique IDs.  What are you going to do with the QR after it is scanned?

Comment: Hi Terence the guid is a unique identifier for each row in our database. we cannot reduce it. Our application is distributed across various platform and database and we need a consistent unique identifier. It was part of existing application and we cannot change it. Is there any waya i can compress this string to store to print in QR code which can be easily read by the mobile phone scanners.

Comment: The guid is 36 characters.. i have data in format 1:guid1;2:guid2;3:guid3.... which is about 800 to 1000 characters...

Comment: What is the point of putting it in a QR code? Will it form part of a URL that the phone will open? Or is it a custom application?

Comment: It is a custom application.. The QR will contain the unique data id of the database records. This way a QR code data printed from one device can be accessed by other mobile mobile device.

Answer (score 2):

In your question you have the following sample data:

> ```
> 1=0a0a8907-40b9-4e81-8c4d-d01af26efb78;2=cd4713339;3=Cjdnd;
> 4=19120581-21e5-42b9-b85f-3b8c5b1206d9;5=hdhsfsdfsd;6=30a21
> 580-48f3-40e8-87a3-fa6e39e6412f; ..............
> ```

Where 1, 4 & 6 looks like version 4 UUIDs as described [here](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt). I suspect that 2, 3 and 5 might also actually be UUIDs?!

The binary representation of a UUIDs are 128 bits long, and they should be fairly simple to convert to this representation by just reading the hex digits of the UUIDs and convert to binary. This gives 16 bytes per UUID.

**However** - as the UUID's are version 4, they are based on random data, that in effect counter further compression (appart from the few bits representing the UUID version). So apart from getting rid of the counters (`1=`, `2=`) and the seperater: `;`, no further compression seem to be possible.

Answer (score 0):

QR codes encode data using different character sets depending on the range of characters being used. IOW, if you use just ascii digits it will use an encoding that doesn't use 8 bits per digit. See the wikipedia page on QR codes.

Because of the characters in your example, e.g., lower case, you'll be using a binary encoding which is way overkill for your actual information content.

Presuming you have control over the decoder, you could use any compression library to take your ascii data and compress it before encoding, encode/decode the binary result, and then decompress it in the decoder. There are a world of techniques for trying to get the most out of the compression. You can also start with a non-ascii encoding and elminate redudant information like the #= parts.

Couldn't say, though, how much this will buy you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to a database already, can you create a table to support this?  If so, archive the value and use an ID for QR.

1) Simple schema: ID = bigint with Identity (1000,1) and set as primary key, Value = NVARCHAR(MAX).  Yes this is a bit overkill, so modify to taste.

2) Create a function to add your string value to the table and get the ID back as a string for the QR code.

3) Create another function to return the string value when passed a valid ID number.

Stays below the 200 character limit for a very long time.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the whole guid; that could eliminate all but one record out of 2^128 records (enough to address every bit of digital information on earth many times over).

How many records do you need to eliminate? Probably a lot less than 4 billion right? That's 2^32, so just take the first 1/4 of the guid and there's your 1000 characters to 250.